# Managing os-specific libraries with Ivy

Tags: java, ant, ivy

Assuming there's a os-specific library ( .so/.dll ) attached to a Java project, what's the way of handling this using Ivy?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way... in our organisation, we're bundling java vms, and in our ivy repository, there's no differentiation - they all get downloaded, and it's up to the build script to figure out which one to use.

Some feature may have been missed, but we've got pretty extensive build procedures, and people with expertise, so I think you're on your own.

In any case, you're going to need to "determine" your OS somehow (in your build script), so it shouldn't be too difficult to write some extra code to determine which extensions to use (our jvm packs have the name of the OS in them - you could switch on .dll/.so extension etc)

Comment: Newer versions of Ivy (2.0+) provide a solution to this problem with ["Extra" attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21103611/2074605).